# RapidXML compilation error parsing string

Tags: c++, string, xml-parsing, rapidxml

I have been having some trouble using RapidXML to parse a string. I receive an error from within Eclipse claiming the parse function does not exist.

```
make all 
Building file: ../search.cpp
Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler
g++ -DDEBUG -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"search.d" -MT"search.d" -o "search.o" "../search.cpp"
../search.cpp: In function ‘void search(CURL*, CURLcode, std::string, std::string)’:
../search.cpp:29:27: error: no matching function for call to ‘rapidxml::xml_document<>::parse(const char*)’
../search.cpp:29:27: note: candidate is:
../rapidxml-1.13/rapidxml.hpp:1381:14: note: template<int Flags> void rapidxml::xml_document::parse(Ch*) [with int Flags = Flags, Ch = char]
make: *** [search.o] Error 1
```

The following code raises an error:

```
rapidxml::xml_document<> doc;    // This has no errors
doc.parse<0>(data.c_str());      // This line raises the error (data is a string)
```

For reference here is the online documentation:
http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/manual.html#namespacerapidxml_1parsing

RapidXML comes as four header files:

1. rapidxml_iterators.hpp
2. rapidxml_print.hpp      <--contains errors, but build is successful with them
3. rapidxml_utils.hpp      <--contains errors, but build is successful with them
4. rapidxml.hpp            <--linked by program, contains parse function

How do I resolve the error in my code, and do I first need so resolve compiler errors in the headers somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the `char*` returned from calling `c_str()` on a `std::string` is actually a `const char*` which is no good for the parse function (parsing actually changes the string that it parses in rapidXML). This means we need to copy the string before we parse it

```
  xml_document<> doc;
  string str;                             // String you want to parse
  char* cstr = new char[str.size() + 1];  // Create char buffer to store string copy
  strcpy (cstr, str.c_str());             // Copy string into char buffer

  doc.parse<0>(cstr);                     // Pass the non-const char* to parse()

  // Do stuff with parsing

  delete [] cstr;                         // free buffer memory when all is finished
```

I have not attempted to compile the above so there maybe errors, the point is that `c_str()` returns a `const char*` and `parse()` must take a non-const `char*`. Hope this helps. As for your headers, I usually get away with only using

```
 rapidxml.hpp
 rapidxml_print.hpp
```

included in my source files. You have no linker issues because RapidXML is header only implementation (which makes it nice in my opinion).

Comment: Thanks for this! It was driving me crazy!

Comment: alternatively, you can avoid the copy by calling parse on a pointer to the strings first member. `doc.parse<0>(&str[0]);`

Comment: @Hydranix I try your method but it didn't work. I'm still trying to figure out a way to parse a string without having to duplicate the memory by copying the string to a char array. I'll post the answer here if I find it.

Comment: @Jaime By 'didn't work'  do you mean it copied the string, or that it did not parse at all? Using gcc 6.3.1 i can successfully parse massive std::strings of xml.

Answer (score 1):

As @Hydranix pointed out in the comments,

```
doc.parse<0>(&str[0]);
```

works perfectly well. I parsed some big xml files using it.