# RapidXML android ndk trouble parsing document

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, rapidxml

I'm having trouble compiling this for android:

```
string buffer = readString(m_paths[SCREEN]);
if (buffer != "")
{
    //Read full buffer
    xml_document<> doc;
    doc.parse<0>((char*)buffer.c_str());
}
```

It works well on VS2010 but for some reason its failing in the ndk, it returns this error:

```
error:exception handling disabled, use -fexceptions to enable
```

I've searched and I found this:
[RapidXML compilation error parsing string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604818/rapidxml-compilation-error-parsing-string)

I've tried it but it also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you what to do: `use -fexceptions to enable`.

You would add that to your Android.mk, `APP_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions -frtti`.

Also, your code is wrong. Change your code to `doc.parse<0>(&buffer[0]);`. `c_str()` returns a **const** char pointer which is non-modifiable, however `parse` modifies the contents so you need to pass the underlying buffer.

Comment: not working...it continues to return that error, thanks anyway :)

Comment: @DanielSanchez: I've updated my answer. You have two problems: 1) You don't have exceptions enabled, and 2) Your code is trying to modify read-only memory.

Comment: Compiled!!! Thanks, it was the flag.... you saved my day, anytime you came to Madrid...send me a message, you have free Beer :)